# How to protect from HTML <base> tag?

Tags: html, radix

Documentation about the tag says it must located inside of the `<head>` and only one `<base>` tag is permitted.

However, this tag successfully replaces base URL for relative links even its been put somewhere inside the `<body>`.

The behavior was noticed in a support ticket system with many relative links. The system renders emails, and if an email's HTML code contains the `<base>` tag, after the email is rendered, all relative links change to the base URL specified in the tag.

The behavior confirmed for Firefox, Chromium-based browsers, Edge. IE11 ignores it. You can check a simple sample [here](http://jsbin.com/jewakam).

Is it possible to protect from such behavior without changing website's HTML markup?

Comment: What can you change? And where is that base tag coming from?

Comment: @Salketer `<base>` comes from an incoming email. The app is a java-based website. Based on this and the suggestion below, seems like there nothing I can do except replacing/upgrading the app.

Comment: What did you expect you could do? You got something incoming that you cannot play with, displayed by something you cannot change... There's absolutely nothing you can do even if the problem was very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Quentin suggested, the best way to protect your HTML from unwanted HTML is to simply get rid of it before displaying it. Unfortunately, sometimes this will break things! Like in this particular example, if the user sent a will containing a `<base>` and relative links, removing the tag would break all the links.

To circumvent this, one could use an `iframe`. They are a very useful tool to sandbox foreign code. This should not be used blindly tough...

As to answer OP, if you have no control over the application used to read the e-mails, your only hope is to tinker with the e-mails themselves. You could create a hook on the inbox to strip down any unwanted HTML (using @Quentin's suggestion) before putting it into the monitored inbox.

Answer (score 2):

Don't blindly insert an email into an HTML document. Treat it like any other potential source for an XSS attack.

If you are going to allow HTML, then run it through a DOM aware white-list based filter (e.g. HTML Purifier if you are using PHP).

`<base>` should not be allowed on the white-list.